# Moving average on 3D array in Dask

Tags: python, arrays, dask

I have a 3D array and I would like to use Dask to chunk up my 3D array into blocks of traces of a certain window size around each trace. A trace is just one vector of size (1, 1, z). I can do this using the numpy as_strided tricks as follows:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import as_strided
input_volume = np.linspace(1, 1000, 1000, dtype=int).reshape((10, 10, 10))
window_size = 5
x, y, z = input_volume.shape

# Create a view on the volume of sub-cubes window_size traces wide overlapping by 1 trace in each direction
half_w = (window_size - 1) // 2
padded = np.pad(input_volume[...], [(half_w, half_w), (half_w, half_w), (0, 0)], 'edge')
x_str, y_str, z_str = padded.strides
blocks = as_strided(padded, (x, y, window_size, window_size, z), (x_str, y_str, x_str, y_str, z_str))
averaged_volume = np.mean(blocks, (2, 3))
```

First I pad my 3D cube in the x and y dimensions by the half window. I get the average trace from each block so in this case a block of (5, 5, z) gets reduced to a single trace. I then end up with a volume the same size as the original that has been averaged over the window size. This effectively gives me a "view" of my 3D array with as shape of (10, 10, 5, 5, 10).

This works but if the volume is large it will load the whole volume into memory.

I have been trying to achieve the same thing with a chunked array in dask but I'm having trouble getting the depth and boundaries correct to give me the same answer. How can I achieve the same thing in dask so it only loads each block of traces into memory at a time and writes back out to the average cube?

EDIT:
This is the dask code I have been trying so far but when this runs I get an IndexError: tuple index out of range when it's trying to do the average calculation:

```
def average(block):
    return np.mean(block, axis=(0, 1))

import dask.array as da
dask_volume = da.from_array(da.pad(input_volume, [(half_w, half_w), (half_w, half_w), (0, 0)], 'edge'), chunks=(window_size ,window_size, -1))
dask_overlapping = da.overlap.overlap(dask_volume, depth={0: window_size - 1, 1: window_size -1}, boundary={0: 'none', 1: 'none'})
dask_average = dask_overlapping.map_blocks(average, chunks=(1, 1, z)).compute()
```

Thanks,

Mike